# Django model modification

Tags: python, django, web, django-models

Ok, i have this django app, where the user fills in their detail and then create a web profile(username and password)

```
from django.db import models

class UserDetail(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name


class WebDetail(UserDetail):
    # user = models.OneToOneField(UserDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

and when i create a user that has a webdetail, it shows empty in the database(django admin)

I need help to link the WebDetail to inherit from the userdetail and also they could show up in the database(django admin)

Thanks for your contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this article on model inheritance and there was this comment at the end of the article that stated the following:

"Whoever is reading this in the future make sure you add the following method to each product type class e.g:

```
class Label(Product):
    objects = LabelManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.product_type = 'Label'
        return super(Label, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Otherwise you won't be able to see your object after it's creation. Cheers :)"

Here's the [link](https://dev.to/zachtylr21/model-inheritance-in-django-m0j) to the article. It's all on model inheritance and it looks like the above code should help with your problem of an empty database after you create a user that has a WebDetail. I would try adding something similar to your WebDetail class.

Comment: Thanks I've checked it. It helped